# Can't get FlowDocument / RichTextBox text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox, flowdocument

Ia have RichTextBox with content defined as following:

```
                    <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph x:Name="para">
                        <Label Padding="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink_Click">
                                <Run Text="{Binding Txt}" x:Name="rxm" />
                            </Hyperlink>
                        </Label>
                        <Label Padding="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" Content=" - " />
                        <Label Padding="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" x:Name="name" Content="Some name"
                   ToolTipService.ShowDuration="10000">
                            <Label.ToolTip>
                                <ContentControl Content="Tooltip" />
                            </Label.ToolTip>
                        </Label>
                    </Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
```

The problem is that I'm not able to get selected text properly. I'm getting few whitespaces instead. So i tried to retrieve all FlowDocument's text at least with following piece of code:

```
            TextRange tr = new TextRange(
          doc.Selection.Start,
          doc.Selection.End);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        tr.Save(ms, DataFormats.Xaml);
        string xamlString =
           ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

It turned out, that I'm getting just few runs with blank space in each of them:

```
<Section xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" ...  <Paragraph>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run> </Run>
    <Run> </Run>
</Paragraph>
```

Looks like the "document" view is completely different from visual view although i have no idea why these Runs are empty. Does anybody know how to get the selected text (even without any formatting) properly? Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable solution:

[How can I copy WPF FlowDocument InlineUIContainer contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611552/how-can-i-copy-wpf-flowdocument-inlineuicontainer-contents)

[Determining the selected InlineUIContainer in a WPF RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651101/determining-the-selected-inlineuicontainer-in-a-wpf-richtextbox)

It'd be quite a lot of coding to handle every possible FlowDocument content but i'm happy with it for now